# Extract Zip File with 100% Compression Ratio

Tags: r, zip, opendata

I noticed this problem when trying to run the following R script.

```
library(downloader)
download('http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_Feb_2016.zip', 
         dest = 'dataset.zip', mode = 'wb')
npi <- read.csv(unz('dataset.zip', 'npidata_20050523-20160207.csv'), 
                as.is = TRUE)
```

The script kept spinning for some reason so I manually downloaded the data and noticed the compression ratio was 100%.

[image]

I am not certain if StackOverflow is the best Exchange for this question, so I am open to moving this question is another Exchange is suggested. The Open Data Exchange might be appropriate, but there isn't very much activity on that site.

My question is this: I work a lot with government curated data from Centers for Medicare and Medicaid Services (CMS). The data downloads from this site are in the form of zip files and occasionally, they have zip ratios of 100%. This is clearly impossible since the uncompressed size is ~800PB. (CMS notes on their site that they estimate the uncompressed size to be ~4GB.) This has affected me on my work computer; I have replicated this problem with co-worker's computer as well as my own personal computer.

One example can be found [here](http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html). (Click the link and then click on NPPES Data Dissemination). There are other examples I've noticed and I've emailed CMS about this. They respond that the files are large and can't be handled with Excel. I am aware of this and this isn't really the problem I'm facing.

Does any one know why this would be happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: You are asking R to unzip and load a very large file (which will be slow).  How long did you wait?  Also, how much RAM do you have?  That big of a file is likely going to be enormous in R.  I tried your script verbatim on my machine and watched as the RAM continued to climb.  I am confident it would finish but I don't have enough RAM to load the whole file.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have 16GB RAM on my computer. I just thought that maybe I should try using `read_csv` from the `readr` package to increase the speed and I'd also get the nice progress bar. I guess I just got worried when I saw that 100% compression ratio and thought something more fundamental was wrong. I'll try `readr` and follow up. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI - the zip is 579M, unzipped about 5.8GB, so definitely not 100% compression. Loading works OK, but eats a lot of memory (im running on 64GB RAM though)

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. When I said the compression ratio was 100%, I meant that my system is showing it to be that high, not that it actually is that high. I am going to try this on another system. I am currently running Win 7, 16GB, Core i7, R v. 3.2.3. I am starting to worry that this is less of an R problem and more of a problem involving how my system handles the zip file that is downloaded since others have been able to make it work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Per cdetermans point, what is the available system memory you have available for R to execute the uncompressing and subsequent loading of the data?  Looking at both the image you posted, and the link to the actual data, which reads as ~560mb compressed, it did not pose a problem on my system ( Win 10, 16 GB, Core i7, R v.3.2.3) to download, uncompress, read the uncompressed CSV into a table.

I would recommend - if nothing else works - to *decouple* your uncompressing and data loading steps. Might even go as far as invoking (depending on your OS) a R system command to decompress your data, manually inspect, and then separately issue piecewise read.tables on the dataset.

Best of luck
rudycazabon